# Chrome for Android: How to see network console information?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is there any way to see networking information on mobile Chrome, ala the networking tab on fully fledged desktop Chrome, on the device itself? I'm attempting to try some remote debugging for a user but I can't really ask them to install the required software to test on a desktop. I need to see if any scripts / etc are failing to load.

Am I out of luck?

Comment: There are a lot of links showing in `chrome://chrome-urls/`, but I think what you want to do requires connecting the device locally in USB debugging mode and seeing the results on your desktop. ([Remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging))

Answer (score 0):

I have written an Xposed module that allows a user to use Developer tools on Chrome for Android. See my Xposed module [ChromeXt](https://github.com/JingMatrix/ChromeXt).

Here are some screenshots of the Network tab:

1. Using the eruda console

   [image: Open Eruda Console by ChromeXt]
2. Using the DevTools

   [image: Open DevTools by ChromeXt]